# Equation of a line through a point that intersects two crossing lines.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the equation of a line through a point, $P(7,1,1)$, that intersects two crossing lines $a$ and $b$. Where

$$
a\;\begin{cases}2x+z&=0\\2x-y-1&=0\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and  }\quad
b\;\begin{cases}2x+z-5&=0\\x-3y&=0.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Find an equation for the plane that contains $P$ and $a$. Find an equation for the plane that contains $P$ and $b$. Put those two together, and you will have a system of equations for your line (provided the situation is "in a general position").

Comment: Yes, but how? I have tried and failed, could you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is one trick to all of this. The trick is: if a line is given by a system of two linear equations, then an equation for any plane that contains that line can be found as a linear combination of said two equations.

To be specific, let us find an equation of the plane that contains point $P$ and line $a$. Line $a$ is given by the system of two equations: $2x + z = 0$ and $2x - y - 1 = 0$. Let's think about this question: what object is given by the following equation
$$
\alpha(2x + z) + \beta (2x - y - 1) = 0,
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two constants?

I know this looks out of the blue, but please bear with me. If both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are zero, then the equation just says $0=0$, and thus the equation defines the whole space. This isn't very interesting.

But what if at least one of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is non-zero? Then this is a linear equation, so it specifies a plane. Also, this plane contains line $a$ (do you understand why?).

Now, you might wonder, what do $\alpha$ and $\beta$ affect? Well, they affect which plane exactly we are talking about. There are infinitely many planes that contain line $a$, and each one can be achieved with an appropriate choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Now, we want to choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in such a way that the resulting plane contains point $P$. How do we do that? Easy. We just substitute coordinates of $P$ into our equation and we get:
$$
\alpha(2\cdot 7 + 1) + \beta(2\cdot 7 - 1 - 1) = 0.
$$
We may choose, for instance, $\alpha = 4$ and $\beta = -5$. This is not the only possible choice (we can multiply both numbers by a common factor and get another solution), but the exact choice isn't important. These particular $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will do just fine.

Now, with these particular $\alpha$ and $\beta$ our equation becomes:
$$
\begin{align}
4(2x + z) - 5(2x - y - 1) &= 0\quad \text{i.e.} \\
-2x + 5y + 4z + 5 &= 0.
\end{align}
$$
This is it. The final equation specifies a plane that contains both $P$ and $a$. At this point it may be wise to actually check this. With $P$ you can just substitute $x=7$, $y=1$, $z=1$ and see that the equation is satisfied. With $a$ this is automatic (again, do you see why?). But if you have doubts, you can actually find a couple of points on line $a$ and see for yourself that both of them satisfy the final equation.

And this is half of the problem. Now you can do the same with line $b$ instead of $a$ and get another plane equation. Adding it to the one above will give you a system of two equations for the very line that you need.

Comment: Thank you. That clears things up